# Bootstrap show only badge on small screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

I have a dashboard (MVC Razor + Bootstrap) navigation bar with these labels and badge

```
    <span class="btn btn-danger" style="pointer-events: none;">Alert<span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">@alerts</span></span>
    <span class="btn btn-warning" style="pointer-events: none;">Waring<span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">@warning</span></span>
    <span class="btn btn-success" style="pointer-events: none;">Normal<span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">@normal</span></span>
```

I would like that on small screen show only badge. How can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `d-none d-md-inline d-lg-inline`-bootstrap class name to hide particular elements on small screen.

I hope this is what u r expecting.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<span class="btn btn-danger"><span class="d-none d-md-inline d-lg-inline" style="pointer-events: none;">Alert</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">@alerts</span></span>


<span class="btn btn-warning"><span class="d-none d-md-inline d-lg-inline" style="pointer-events: none;">Waring</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">@warning</span></span>

<span class="btn btn-success"><span class="d-none d-md-inline d-lg-inline" style="pointer-events: none;">Normal</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">@normal</span></span>
```